# Customer address is too big for POS receipt

Tags: pos, receipt

I'm using this line to add customer address to my POS receipt:

```
graphics.DrawString(
     "Address: " + _selectedCustomer.address, 
     new Font("Calibri", 8), 
     new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 
     startX + 15, 
     startY + Offset
);
```

but the problem is customer address is way too big for my receipt ( 35 to 40 char).
I need to make the string wrap in 2 or 3 lines based on the length of the customer address.

[image]

Comment: Split string in chunk and print line by line.

Comment: If you already know what to do, what is your question?

Comment: i don't know what to do with big length address, it showing as 1 line and in the print out the address is not full, i want to make show in 2 or 3 lines. i have added a pic of my receipt showing the out of line address